# Class или struct в Swift?

Tags: swift, классы

Когда лучше использовать класс, а когда структуру в Swift?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Основное различие в том, что структуры передаются по значению, а классы — по ссылке. С точки зрения производительности важно, что экземпляры структур могут быть созданы в стеке, а экземпляры классов — только в куче.

В соответствии с [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_108):

> Структуры подходят, если выполняется одно или несколько условий:
>
> - Инкапсуляция небольшого набора простых значений.
> - Значения следует копировать, а не передавать по ссылке.
> - Свойства самой структуры — value-типы, которые тоже передаются по значению.
> - Структуры не наследует свойства или поведения.
>
> Хорошие примеры:
>
> - Размеры фигуры: ширина и высота.
> - Точка в пространства: x, y и z типа double.
>
> В большинстве случаев следует использовать классы.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такие вопросы себе задавать:
1) Нужно ли мне наследование?
2) Нужно ли использовать классовые дженерики ('class SomeClass: ClassName')?
3) Нужно ли будет такое, чтобы инстанс объекта был доступен из нескольких мест и его можно было менять из них. (объект по ссылке, вместо копирования)?
4) Нужен ли деинициализатор?

Если на все ответ нет, то используйте структуру.